# Removing product Link from the product price on content-product.php template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, product

I am using the Woocommerce WP plugin. On my Shop page, I would like to remove the link `<a>` to the product page from the `<span class="price">`.

In [this](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/woocommerce-remove-link-to-product-page/) article the author is suggesting to alter the  tags in */your-child-theme/woocommerce/content-product.php* WooCommerce template, but this is no longer possible in the newest WooCommerce version 2.6+.

I have only found a way to remove the whole link, not just the price-link.

How can I move the link only from the price?

Here it is what i would like:

```
<a href="www.link-to-single-product.com">
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
    <img width="300" height="200" src="www.link.com">

</a> <!-- <===== TO HERE -->

    <span class="price">
        <span class="amount">PRICE</span>
    </span>

</a> <!-- Moving this close tag FROM HERE -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update2** (there where 2 missing "**`;`**" in the code, that was doing the 500 error. So you should retry.

Here is an extract from content-product.php template (with solution (1) and (2):

```
/**
 * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
 * <===  <===  <===  <===  <===  <===  <===  <===  <=== (2) To here
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10  ====> (1) From here
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );

/**
 * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item hook.
 * 
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close - 5  ==> (2) From here
 * <===  <===  <===  <===  <===  <===  <===  <===  <===  <=== (1) To here
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
```

**So there is 2 alternatives to achieve take out the price from `<a href="…></a>`:**

1. We are going to try to unhook **`'woocommerce_template_loop_price'`** from one location to another just after **`'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close'`** hooked function.

Then you could try to add this code snippet to the function.php file of your active child theme:

```
add_action('init', function(){
   remove_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
   add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 7);
}
```

2. We are going to try to unhook **`'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close'`** from one location to another just before **`'woocommerce_template_loop_price'`** hooked function.

Then you could try to add this code snippet to the function.php file of your active child theme:

```
add_action('init', function(){
   remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );
   add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 7);
}
```

I haven't test it yet, but this time it should work without error 500.

You can try them also `add_action('init', function(){ … }` in case.

**The final working Solution *(chosed by [fjott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6553529/fjott) )***

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 7);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can disable the Link to Products @ Loop only adding 2 line code, I have test it into my client store and its working. You need to put that below 2 link code into your child-them functions.php.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );
```